# Fedora Core 39 Disable zram0

Tags: fedora, swap, zram

Background:
I have several VMs that do not need sleep or other things.  I generally provide them enough RAM to do their job and not need swap. I kickstart them and build them without a swap partition.  Since Fedora Core 37 (or before) zram has been enabled.

Question:
How  do you disable this feature (zram0) since this is not a host that will need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by Fedora Project[1]:
touch /etc/systemd/zram-generator.conf

However If there is a configuration existing using copy "null" and it will zero out the file as well as create it if it does not exist. The chattr +i will prevent upgrades from re-enabling it.

```
cp /dev/null /etc/systemd/zram-generator.conf  
chattr +i  /etc/systemd/zram-generator.conf
```

1.) https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SwapOnZRAM#How_can_it_be_disabled

Comment: If you are having issues with run-away CPU usage on kswapd0 you might try this to see can help remedy the issue.  YMMV.